# What time complexity is a reachability algorithm?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, time-complexity

I've read there are ways you can determine all reachable pairs using Strongly Connected Components. But, I want to calculate all reachable nodes on the fly - so I don't have to store a massive reachability matrix in RAM. What sort of time complexity would be possible for an algorithm to calculate all reachable nodes in a directed graph, from a single node?

[image]

Here's a naive algorithm I came up with, I'm not sure of the time complexity of this. $O(V!)$?

It seems to have an $O(V)$ spacial complexity though.

I've read about the Bellman-Ford algorithm with a time complexity of $O(EV)$ which is essentially $O(V^3)$ and the Floyd-Warshall algorithm which is $O(V^3)$. They require $O(V)$ and $O(V^2)$ space complexity, respectively.

The problem is only inputs can be determined in constant time. So, one would have to find (in $O(V)$ time)  all outputs for a particular node. What I actually did in my solution is invert the graph using a similar technique, before running DFS. But I don't know if this is optimal... Also, due to a copy of the graph being stored in memory, my solution has a spacial complexity worse than the bellman-ford algorithm. If this time complexity is also worse, I may as well use bellman fords algorithm

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "inputs" or "neuron".

Comment: The representation of the directed graph in memory is recursive, each node has a set of inputs.

Comment: Rather than responding in the comments, please edit the question to clarify.  Please either avoid using $n$, or define what it represents in the question.  I see the question still uses $n$.  I don't know what it means to say that the representation is recursive, and I still don't know what it means for a node to have inputs.  Do you mean incoming edges?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate all reachable nodes in $O(V+E)$ time and $O(V)$ space, using DFS on the fly.

If you want to use less than $O(V)$ space, then the problem becomes much more challenging.  I recommend looking at how the [SPIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPIN_model_checker) model checker works.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitstate_hashing.  Even then, the space required is probably still $O(V)$, just with a lower constant factor.

Comment: DFS works if you can traverse a nodes outputs, in constant time. As explained, only the inputs can be traversed (In constant time)

Comment: Do you think this is optimal?

Comment: Inversion of a graph (to prepare for DFS) works in $O(E)$ time, and DFS obviously works in $O(V+E)$. The spacial complexity however is now $O(V^2)$ as an inverted graph is (briefly) stored in memory.